# can a click event be triggered on absolutely stacked elements?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a click event thats firing. It's working great and does what I need it to do. Here's the problem

The nature of the widget i'm building stacks elements on top of each other through `position: absolute` When i click on one of these stacked elements, only one event is firing, but id like every element to fire that is under the mouse cursor of the click. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: does your click handler attach to all those stack elements or just one?

Comment: its a view class, each button that gets rendered through the class has its own event listener, that when clicked it starts to rotate. Right now only one elements event gets triggered, i want all of them to trigger that my mouse falls under

Comment: the events works, i just have to continually click as one rotates off, i'd like to be able to click and if it happens to be on multiple, i want it to fire all of them

Comment: You can Hide the top element and get the next absolute element's co-ordinate with `document.elementFromPoint` and then repeat and then show them at the end. Please check the demo for idea.

Comment: that looks liek it would work. What i ended up doing is just finding all els that reside where the mouse is and firing the click manually, I'll give you the check for it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the demo or run the code snippet in full page and click through all the divs to see the result message.

**DEMO:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/KRWvLmRhGbO200pFkOxL?p=preview

What I am doing here is :

Hide the top element

and

get the next absolute element's co-ordinate with `document.elementFromPoint` and then repeat.

**Stack Snippet:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $common = $("div.common").on('click.passThrough', function (e, ee) {
      var $element = $(this).hide();
      try {
        if (!ee) $("#output").empty();
        $("<div/>").append('You have clicked on: '+$element.text()).appendTo($("#output"));
        ee = ee || {
          pageX: e.pageX,
          pageY: e.pageY
        };
        var next = document.elementFromPoint(ee.pageX, ee.pageY);
        next = (next.nodeType == 3) ? next.parentNode : next //Opera
        $(next).trigger('click.passThrough', ee);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("click.passThrough failed: " + err.message);
      } finally {
        $element.show();
      }
    });
    
    $common.css({'backgroundColor':'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'});
});
```

```css
#output {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.common {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 3px; 
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}
.elem5 {
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
}
.elem4 {
  top: 180px;
  left: 180px;
}
.elem3 {
  top: 210px;
  left: 210px;
}
.elem2 {
  top: 240px;
  left: 240px;
}
.elem1 {
  top: 270px;
  left: 270px;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
<div class="common elem1">Top Most Element</div>
<div class="common elem2">Element 2</div>
<div class="common elem3">Element 3</div>
<div class="common elem4">Element 4</div>
<div class="common elem5">Bottom Element</div>
```

Credit for source:

http://jsfiddle.net/E9zTs/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use customEvent property

Place all div in a parent div

add a click handler to the parent div

if there is a click in the parent box..determine whether the click is in any of the child boxes

If true. then send a click event to all child box

snippet

```js
//This function changes the color of all child divs
function changeColor(e) {
  this.style.background = "red";
}

//this function is attached to the parent div which will send that click event to all divs
function trigger(e) {
  //create an event
  event = new CustomEvent('click');
  //if the event originates from a child div
  if (e.target.className == 'box')
  //loop through all child div
    for (var i = 0; i < all_box.length; ++i) {
    //dispatch a click event to each child div
    all_box[i].dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('click', trigger)
var all_box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
for (var i = 0; i < all_box.length; ++i) {
  all_box[i].addEventListener('click', changeColor)
}
```

```css
.box {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid black;
}
#parent {
  border: solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
;
<div id="parent">
  <div class="box" id="primary">box1</div>
  <div class="box">box2</div>
  <div class="box">box3</div>
  <div class="box">box3</div>
</div>
```